# Non-religious to religious help!

Tags: observance

This is a personal question and I am seeking some guidance. Here is a little bit of background information so that you understand a little of what the situation is.

So both of my parents are Jewish and both have grown up non-observant and their house was also not strict on being observant or not. They moved to the U.S and have lost connection with almost all their Jewishness. My mother was convinced to go to this church and she decided to go and she said she liked it and then my father also started going. Then we all went together because it was the "normal" thing to do, however my mother never really studied it, but my father did and for some reason he studied the Torah more (which is good of course). This continued and when I was 13 or 14 my father started to tell me about his parents and his grandparents on how they were Jewish but never were observant. He studied even more Torah along with the new testament and came to the conclusion that church wasn't for him and that he wanted to be more observant in Torah because it feels right and it feels better. I was just introduced to the idea that I am Jewish and I personally grew up all my life inside a church, but I always had doubts on many things. I started to look into it and once my mother noticed I was getting more interested about Judaism and that I started observing very slow with the "easy" stuff like keeping Kosher and the Shema, she became very angry. And I still do not understand why, but whenever my father and I would have a conversation about Torah, she would intervene and start talking about church (even though she doesn't study, not even the new testament, she just goes to church). But this has been going on for the past 5 years and the more my father and I learn and start to become little more observant, the more she denies her Jewishness. She even recently said that she doesn't believe in any of this (the Torah) and this made me really really upset.
I think it is good to mention that my parents weren't married the Jewish way, and that my father and I are scared to contact local Rabbis because we don't really have solid proof of our Jewishness and that we strayed from Judaism by going to church. Oh and I have two younger siblings and sometimes we try to teach them Torah as well by my mom intervenes by telling them that it doesn't matter and that they can do whatever because its an "old book" and things of these sorts.

So now there is some context, my question is how can I be more observant in an essentially non-religious household. My mother hates it whenever my father and I bring up anything from the Torah. We don't even light Shabbat candles and Pesach is next week and she refuses to throw anything away. It makes me cry and I am very saddened because I truly want to observe all of these things, but is there a point in trying if I can't even fulfill the entire mitzva? What should I do? My father and I have completely left the church and have done Teshuva for this sin, but my mother goes at least once a month now because she doesn't like going by herself, and my father has been trying to show my mother a little more and more of the Torah and remind her of her Jewishness but she doesn't listen to a single word. Is there anything I can do, should I even try to show her Torah or try to get her to do what is right? At least even allow us to fulfill these mitzvot?

Sorry for the long story and questions, but there is just so much going on and it breaks my heart that this is the case. 
Thank you very much and may H'Shem bless you!

Comment: Wow. I don't really think I'm qualified to give advice but there is always point in trying.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look over our [tour] for some guidance on how to use the site, as it's probably different from some others you're used to. Unfortunately we [do not](http://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) offer personalized advice here; those sorts of questions should be directed [to your Rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Comment: This is something that you need to discuss with a rabbi. The current situation makes it more difficult. I have found that many time a person (like your mother) will refuse to admit that she hd made a mistake. Thus, she may not really believe in the church mythology but just feels guilty for having gone to church and doing the wrong thing. As a result, the more that she (in her heart) realizes that she has been wrong, the more she fights against admitting that she was wrong. In any case the Chabad rabbi in your community may be able to help you or point you to someone who can help

Comment: @doubleAA Is asking for advice the same as asking for a psak?

Comment: @Loewian In this case asking for advice is still not appropriate for this forum. It would be better to speak in person with a rabbi who can discuss the circumstance of the individual case.